# Service Provider Interface in recent Xodus release

Tags: java, xodus

The most recent release of Xodus states:

> This release offers Service Provider Interface for I/O customization
>   in the package jetbrains.exodus.io. In addition to default disk-based
>   I/O, it lets you configure your application to use an in-memory
>   database, or to access in read-only mode disk-based database opened in
>   another JVM. You can also create your own I/O provider, e.g., for
>   storing data in a remote/cloud file system.

Does it mean the S3 is ready or ready to be plugged into Xodus through the SPI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 1.3.0, storing data in any remote/cloud file system is not supported out of the box.